# String variable won't take string value

Tags: android

I'm probably missing something really obvious here. I have created a new string called str but when I try to assign a string value from strings.xml to it I am getting the error "The method getString(int) is undefined for the type String". Not sure why it thinks it is an int?

It works fine if I just set str = "my string"?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_clinics);

}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {

    // initialize the string variable
    String str; 

    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.radioCounty1:
        if (checked)
            str.getString(R.string.County1);
        break;
    case R.id.radioCounty2:
        if (checked)
            str.getString(R.string.County2);
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String` has no member `getString`. You are probably looking for `Context.getString(int)`.

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29) you can find the documentation.

Comment: Yes this worked. Other answers below were more or less the same too. I just don't get what the point of referring to a context is when I am working within one class. Or more to the point why doesn't String have a getString member??

Comment: Context is a class with getString method. Activity extends (in its hierarchy Context), so from an activity you are able to call the getString method. It looks up the R class to get the String you want. String is a java class. It has no notion of Android resources

Answer (score 2):

String has no method named `getString`.

You should use

str = Activity_name.this.getResources().getString(R.string.County1);

Where Activity_name is the name of the current activity

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `str =  getResources().getString(R.string.County1)`  instead

Answer (score 1):

pass a instance of Context context

and then use

context.getResources().getString(R.string.text1)
here context is belongs to your current activity.

Answer (score 1):

Since String does not have getString() you cannot use it directly with String. 
Instead You cannot use

```
str = getResources().getString(R.string.County1);
```

or

```
str = Context.getString(R.string.County1);
```